# Cell values not getting set for newly added rows : using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a table in a ppt slide. Data to the table will be read from an `ArrayList` (Each object in the `ArrayList` will contain one row data) of `String[]`.

If the number of rows in the table is less than the size of the `ArrayList`, new rows will be added to match the size of the `ArrayList`.

Problem here is data is getting set for already existing rows but not for the newly added rows. Please find the code snippet below.

Any help/suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
XSLFTable table = (XSLFTable) shape;
int noOfDataRows=table.getNumberOfRows()-1;
if(noOfDataRows<ap.size()) {
    for(int rws=0;rws<(ap.size()- noOfDataRows);rws++) {
        System.out.println(" Adding row");
        table.addRow();
    }
}

List<XSLFTableRow> rows = table.getRows();

for (int i = 0; i < ap.size(); i++) {
    String[] awaitprop={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'};
    XSLFTableRow row=rows.get(i+1);
    List<XSLFTableCell> cells=row.getCells();
    for(int j=0;j<cells.size();j++) {
        XSLFTableCell cell=cells.get(j);
        cell.clearText();
        XSLFTextParagraph paragraph=cell.addNewTextParagraph();
        paragraph.setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);
        XSLFTextRun textRun=paragraph.addNewTextRun();
        textRun.setFontFamily("Calibri");
        textRun.setFontSize(11);
        textRun.setText(awaitprop[j]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: For your new rows, don't you need to add some cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to following [tutorial](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/Tutorial4.java), at first you should create cell(s) in the new row, I guess. Then you can put a content there.

```
    XSLFTableRow headerRow = table.addRow();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        XSLFTableCell th = headerRow.addCell();
        XSLFTextParagraph p = th.addNewTextParagraph();
        XSLFTextRun r = p.addNewTextRun();
        r.setText("Text");
    }
```

I hope it helps!